# Structuremap - multiple interface implementations

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap

I am totally new to Structuremap and am confused on how to wire an interface that has multiple implementations.

Lets say I have `Controller1` and `Controller2`. I have `Interface1` that is implemented by two separate classes, `Class1ForInterface1` and `Class2ForInterface1`. In `Controller1` I want `Class1ForInterFace1` injected and in `Controller2` I want `Class2ForInterface1` injected.

How do I wire this with structuremap? It seems that I can only have one mapping of Interface to concrete type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It is possible to have several classes implementing the same interface with structuremap.

If you name your mappings, you can retrive them with that name later.

```
For<MyInterface>().Add<Class1ForMyInterface>().Named("Class1");
For<MyInterface>().Add<Class2ForMyInterface>().Named("Class2");
```

If you then want your Class1ForMyInterface then you can call

```
container.GetInstance<MyInterface>("Class1");
```

There is also a couple of ways to map all this in you container aswell

```
For<IController>().Add<Controller1>().Ctor<MyInterface>().Is(i => i.GetInstance<MyInterface>("Class1"));
```

Or if you keep the smartinsatance that is returned when you register a type, you can use it in the mapping.

```
var class1 = For<MyInterface>().Add<Class1ForMyInterface>().Named("Class1");
For<IController>().Add<Controller1>().Ctor<MyInterface>().Is(class1);
```